# Download image URL contains "è"

Tags: android, image

I try to download the image in the following url:

http://upload.tapcrowd.com//cache//_cp_100_100_stand_filière_300x212.jpg

As you can see in the browser this shows an image, but in my app I get a FileNotFoundException.

However if i change the url of the image from "è" to "e". I can succesfully download it into my app. This however is only a temporary solution as it needs to be able to download images with unicode sign.

How can I achieve this?

Method used to download images:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f, maxheight, maxwidth);
```

---

result code that works for me:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        int slashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
        String filename = url.substring(slashIndex + 1);
        filename = URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8");
        url = url.subSequence(0, slashIndex + 1) + filename;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f, maxheight, maxwidth);
```

Comment: probably an encoding issue. you need to urlencode your path (part after the .com)

Comment: I tried URLEncoder.encode(url); but with no succes

Comment: did you specify the encoding or did you use the deprecated encode with only one arg ?

Comment: urlencode should give you something like `http://upload.tapcrowd.com//cache//_cp_100_100_stand_fili%C3%A8re_300x212.jpg`

Comment: can you post the code related to `f` ? How do you create it ?

Comment: @njzk2 you were right, sorry, if you post your comment as an answer I'll set it as correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encode the url using [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
String baseUrl = "http://upload.tapcrowd.com//cache//";
String imageName = "_cp_100_100_stand_filière_300x212.jpg";
URL imageUrl = new URL(baseUrl+URLEncoder.encode(imageName ,"UTF-8"));
```

It works with your browser, because browser is smart enough to do the encoding when you type accent in your url bar.

Comment: that fixed it for me, but njzk2 got that answer first i'll sign his answer correct; thanks